# Why are some of the Stunts in The Expanse RPG labelled 'Core'?

Tags: stunts, age-system, the-expanse-rpg

The system for **The Expanse** is the AGE system, so I'm hoping someone with another game which uses AGE can answer this. Neither **The Expanse** core rules nor the **Blue Rose** RPG have any rules about it!

In all the lists of stunts, the first few have the label **(Core)** written before their name. For instance the first five of the General Combat Stunts are:

- (Core) Adrenaline Rush
- (Core) Momentum
- (Core) Duck and Weave
- Take Cover
- Guardian Angel

What does Core mean? Does it have a game mechanic effect which applies to using or choosing those particular stunts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Core stunts are simply the suggested stunts for each list. The tag has no mechanical effect. [This blog post](https://greenronin.com/blog/2018/04/30/modern-monday-so-many-stunts/) on the publisher's site clarifies that.

> Every stunt list has labeled Core Stunts. These have low or variable
>   costs, and are generally useful, so when you can’t decide on your
>   stunts, these are your picks.

Comment: Possibly also worth noting that, as per https://roninarmy.com/forum/dragon-age-rpg-age-system/the-expanse-rpg/398936-core-stunts, these are non-conditional. They don't depend on a particular situation being present, like Take Cover.